# PHPUnit No such file or directory

Tags: phpunit, symfony4

I'm trying to test my `RoomRepository` with PHPUnit and Symfony 4. I installed `symfony/phpunit-bridge` using `composer`. I created a simple entity called `Room` with one `id` and `name` attributs and a `repository` method to get a `Room` by its `id`.

```php
public function get(int $id): ?Room
{
   /** @var Room $room */
   $room = $this->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

   return $room;
}
```

My test is quite simple as you can see :

```php
public function testGet(): void
{
    /** @var RoomRepository $repository */
    $repository = $this->em->getRepository(Room::class);

    $room = $repository->get(1);

    $this->assertCount(1, $room);
}
```

I am new with test and I don't know if it's the right way to proceed. I followed the Symfony documentation.

So, when I execute the following command :

```
./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit
```

I am getting this error :

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

I am pretty sure this is a commun mistake and very easy to fix...

Furthermore, I wrote other simple asserts that worked very well. I don't think it's about PHPUnit configuration.

Here some informations about my env :

- PHP 7.1
- Symfony4.0.5
- PHPUnit 5.7.27
- Docker with Laradock (containers : mysql, apache2, workspace)

Thanks guys for reading my post and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem – I just forgot to add the database url to the phpunit.xml.dist file. You have to add:

```html
<phpunit ...>
  <php>
    ...
    <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://username:password@server:port/database" />
    ...
  </php>
  ...
</phpunit>
```

Of course with your own credentials instead of the placeholders.